# Set base currency programmatically in Magento2

Tags: magento2, php

I want to set base currency programmatically in magento2. kindly suggest me a solution.

Comment: Please Accept the answer if it helps you in anyway or resolved your issue.
thanks !

Comment: have you tried this tutorial by the mageplaza **https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-currency-data-code-rate-symbol-magento-2.html**

Comment: @MohitRane, mageplaza tutorial is for getting the values, the question is how to set base currency, how that can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use setCurrencycode($code) method to set your store currency programmatically.

Just Inject following class:
Magento/Store/Model/Store

in there a function is defined as:

```
public function setCurrentCurrencyCode($code)
{
     $code = strtoupper($code);
     if (in_array($code, $this->getAvailableCurrencyCodes())) {
            $this->_getSession()->setCurrencyCode($code);

            $defaultCode = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getDefaultStore()->getDefaultCurrency()->getCode();
            $this->_httpContext->setValue(Context::CONTEXT_CURRENCY, $code, $defaultCode);
      }
        return $this;
  }
```

Just Call this function anywhere you want and pass the currency code in the parameter.

Comment: This doesn't work for me @Shubham,

Comment: This code doesn't work for me.

Comment: @jafarpinjar : Please let me know the Magento Version you are using. also pasting your code snippet will help me to assist you better. As last time i checked this was working for me.

Comment: @ShubhamMathur, I used above code in magento 2.3.1

Comment: @ShubhamMathur, could you check it, is it worked for you?